# How can I reset all my TF2 achievements?

Tags: achievements, team-fortress-2

So I stopped playing TF2 for a while and would like to start up again. I played a little bit and it doesn't seem as fun without the achievements. How can I reset these?

Ive tried reset statistics but it did not reset achievements.

P.S. I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there's a completely legit way to do this.

However...

If you're willing to risk a VAC ban (however unlikely it may be), look at the [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam/). Sketchy-looking site, people use the tool to cheat, use at your own risk, etc. etc. etc. [Here](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/9/612823460252649648/) are some old [Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/0/540744474803154175/) of people talking about [SAM](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2354508), as well as a previous [StackExchange post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246591/is-using-a-steam-achievement-manager-against-steam-rules) on the topic. It's against the rules, it's a moral grey area, but for your described purposes, I personally don't see an issue with it.

Otherwise, create a new Steam account, spend $5 on something so you can download all the free games, and start fresh

Comment: Hey I like this program, but I'm on a Mac (sadly). Is there anything hing a ke this for Mac ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but if you have access to a friend's PC or an open library/school computer, you could sign into your Steam account there, download TF2 and SAM, and reset it that way

Comment: Supposedly, you won't get VAC-banned if you aren't in-game while you reset your achievements.
Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/3dqekl/legal_way_to_reset_achievements/

Comment: Not just "supposedly", you are guaranteed you won't get VAC'd. Valve's Anti-cheat will not do anything whatsoever unless you're connected to a VAC-secure server. If you open SAM without TF2 open, you can do anything you want in SAM without any repercussion from Valve.

Answer (score 6):

As of [June 7 2018](https://store.steampowered.com/news/40961/), you can reset achievements in Team Fortress 2 from the "View Achievements" menu.

> - Added "Reset All Achievements" button to the Achievements dialog
>
>   - A small number of achievements are based on player stats and will be awarded again when Team Fortress 2 is restarted unless the player stats are also reset
>   - Resetting achievements will not allow you to receive achievement-based items multiple times
>
> [*Team Fortress 2 Patch Notes - June 7, 2018*](https://store.steampowered.com/news/40961/)

[image: Reset achievements button]

Answer (score 3):

Try: Launch TF2, click "items", select the stats tab, and then select "reset stats" to the bottom right.
Your loadouts will be reset however, and you'll have to re-add the items onto your classes. ([Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2599495))

Alternately, send Valve [a support ticket](https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php) asking to have your achievements for TF2 reset, but expect to wait a week or so. ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/tf2/comments/3dqekl/legal_way_to_reset_achievements/))

Note: Achieving previously achieved achievements again will not result in you getting the achievement items.
([Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/440/discussions/0/620696934039175750/))

Comment: I've done this and it olny reset my stats. Not loadouts, not acheivemtents. :(